# sql and sum by specific dates

Tags: sql, date, sum

I have a question about SQL and how to sum specific rows by year and month

Question: I would like to sum the S&P values for January 2016 (all dates within this month + year
table looks like the following

```
S&PTable
user_id  date      price
1        1/2/2016  1989.00   (sum this)
2        1/3/2016  1987.25   (sum this)
3        1/4/2016  1985.50   (sum this)
4        2/1/2016  2011.25   (don't sum this)
5        3/1/2016  2015.75   (don't sum this)
```

this is how far I got

```
SELECT SUM(price) 
FROM S&PTable
WHERE ?????
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

In most databases you would write:

```
SELECT SUM(price) 
FROM S&PTable
WHERE date >= '2016-01-01' and date < '2016-02-01';
```

Most databases don't accept `&` in a table name, so that would need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `between` to get the result

```
SELECT SUM(price) 
FROM S&PTable
WHERE date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-31';
```